# Call code from event binding with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code bound to the `blur()` event in jQuery:

```
$('input[type="text"]').blur(function () {
    ... some code ...
});
```

Is there a way to invoke this same code from another function in my javascript? Or, do I need to separate this code from the event binding in order to reuse it?

Comment: Even if you could call the handler assigned to the blur event directly, I think it is nicer to create a seperate function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.trigger` to call the event.

For example:

```
$('input[type="text"]').trigger('blur');  // this would call the blur event
                                          // on all the elements
```

Comment: I prefer this syntax; i think it's more clear about exactly what's happening behind the scenes.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you want to call a piece of code form both the blur event handler and elsewhere.  If so then the best way to do this is to define a separate function and call it from both places

```
var theCode = function () {
  ...
};

$('input[type="text"]').blur(function(){
  theCode();
});

// else where
theCode();
```

It is possible to raise the blur event directly from other parts of your code.  However that's a bit of an indirect method of doing it.  I find it's much clearer if you call the intended code directly.

Note as gdoron pointed out in the comments the first blur sample could be shortened to

```
$('input[type="text"]').blur(theCode);
```

Comment: `$('input[type="text"]').blur(function () {theCode();});` => `$('input[type="text"]').blur(theCode);`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to invoke it, just call `blur` method on the element which has `blur` event attached.

```
$('input[type="text"]').blur();
```